# Phalcon Undefined variable

Tags: php, variables, phalcon

I am new to phalcon framework. I have set the variable email in my TblUserController's edit action as

```
$tbl_user = TblUser::findFirstByuser_id($user_id);
$this->view->setVar("email", $tbl_user->email);
```

and in tbl_user/edit.volt I write like:

```
{{ tbl_user.email }}
```

but it gives error

> Undefined variable: tbl_user

Comment: What if you write {{email}} ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Phalcon but I think you need to do:

```
$this->view->setVar("email", $tbl_user->email);
```

And use:

```
{{ email }}
```

Or

```
$this->view->setVar("tbl_user", $tbl_user);
```

And use:

```
{{ tbl_user.email }}
```